# Intent a pagina de configuración

Tags: android, android-intent

Necesito realizar un `Intent` desde una aplicación la cual me lleve a la siguiente página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quería saber si es posible realizar este `Intent`, cabe recalcar que se encuentra en el menú de las configuraciones del teléfono, hasta el momento este es mi código, pero no lleva a la pantalla que muestra la foto:

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
        "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No estas implementando bien el listener del `DialogInterface`, prueba esto:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

if (id == dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
 "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
 startActivity(intent);
 } else if (id== dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE){
 //el usuario ha cancelado
 }
```